# Overriding SilverStripe 3 CommentsInterface.ss

Tags: comments, blogs, silverstripe

I've installed the comments module for my SS 3.0 blog and it's working.

But I want to override the CommentsInterface.ss template and I can't figure out where to put the overriding file. I've tried in themes/mytheme/template and themes/mytheme/templates/Includes and neither seem to work.

This should not be hard, so I must be missing something easy.

Clues?

Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your `CommentsInterface.ss` in `/themes/mytheme/templates/`. 
Then run ?flush=all to flush your template cache so Silverstripe starts using the new template.

Comment: I did that and even the /?flush=all. But it's still not getting picked up. I must be missing something else. But what?

Comment: I'm not sure how I screwed up the first time I tried this, but I did. When I tried it again, it worked just as you described. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As long as I believe this need to put into mysite/templates instead of /themes/mytheme/templates/ . Not sure about the exact reason but it works for me.